# Segmentation Error while trying to volume up

Tags: c++, linux

I have a simulation that I am trying to profile it with `gprof`.

I didn't write it and I am not allowed to add any code. Normally the program runs without errors. It is written in C++.

While program running, when I try to change the volume of the system from keyboard, the program gives the error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` every time.

My system is `Linux 3.8.0-37-generic #53~precise1-Ubuntu x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.
Does it arrive because of the code, which runs perfectly in other systems ? If not what could be the reason?  How can I avoid it?

Comment: Is it written in C (exclusive-)or C++? Also: a segmentation fault can happen for any number of reasons, without seeing the code it's going to be difficult to analyze. If you can't post the code itself maybe you can post a small equivalent example that exhibits the same behaviour.

Comment: What does the core dump "say"?

Comment: run gdb on the core dumped gdb "core" "app"

Comment: @Kninnug sorry, it is written C++. Actually it is not a small code, it is a project and i don't know exactly which part gives this error.  Is there any tools for analyzing it?

Comment: Find the core file. Run `gdb your-executable core-file`. You should see backtrace. If your program was compiled with the -g option then you should see where it coredumped and you can help to fix it.